# Dialogflow Essentials "Training" not working for days. Is there any workaround?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Dialogflow Essentials "Training" not working for days yet the GCP status reads "All services normal"
Any workaround? Am I missing something?

Comment: For me, the Training section is different than before. Now it looks similar to the "History" page. This is really tedious for training. Is there any way to revert this?

Comment: I thought "Training" does not work only in "Trial Edition" but in "Essential Editions" it doesn't work either. Google silence on this matter is really frustrating...